# Fabricjs calculating angle of image

Tags: c#, fabricjs

i am using fabricjs for a graphics application. the UI loads several images from the serverside. The serverside loads a bitmap and the then rotates it, and send the rotated image to fabricjs.

what i want to do is to find out if the user rotated the image as it was before the server rotated it. the serverside rotation angle is know.

i wanted to know if someone know how the angle in fabricjs is calculated or if someone can suggest a way to address this issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily get that with getAngle() method..

```
  selectedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    selectedObject.getAngle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more stuff json file to get all cords like that

```
topLeftCornerX:     toFixed(this.oCoords.tl.x, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
topLeftCornerY:     toFixed(this.oCoords.tl.y, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
topRightCornerX:    toFixed(this.oCoords.tr.x, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
topRightCornerY:    toFixed(this.oCoords.tr.y, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
bottomLeftCornerX:  toFixed(this.oCoords.bl.x, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
bottomLeftCornerY:  toFixed(this.oCoords.bl.y, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
bottomRightCornerX: toFixed(this.oCoords.br.x, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
bottomRightCornerY: toFixed(this.oCoords.br.y, NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS),
```

and read you will have more point to get proper angle.
hope this will work for you